# Slim Twig check is method = posted

Tags: php, twig, slim

Hi i'm learning twig and i'm stuck. It doesn't check if form is submitted so My guess is there is something incorrect.
Can anyone point me to a right way.

```
{% if method == 'POST' %}
Method posted
{% endif %}ˇ
```

My get function

```
$app->get('/p/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {

    $pDItem = $app->pD->where('id', $id)->first();

    if (!$pDItem) {
        $app->notFound();
    }

    $app->render('pD/pDItem.php', [
        'pDItem' => $pDItem,
        'method' => $app->request->getMethod()
    ]);

})->name('pD.item');
```

-

Answer (score 2):

You need to use instead:

```
$app->post('/p/:id', ...);
```

Or to match both `POST` and `GET` methods:

```
$app->map(['POST','GET'], '/p/:id', ...);
```